# WebSphere Liberty 8.0.0.3 Remote EJB Lookup fails

Tags: java, ejb, javabeans, ejb-3.1

WebSphere Liberty 8.0.0.3 EJB Lookup fails:

I created a EJB with the following code and deployed in WebSphere Liberty 8.0.0.3.

**ITestEJBRemoteInterface.java**

```
package ejb31.test;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
@EJB(name="ejb/checkName")
public interface ITestEJBRemoteInterface
{ 
    public boolean checkNames(String fsName);
}
```

**TestEJB.java:**

```
package ejb31.test;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
/** * Session Bean implementation class TestEJB */ 
@Stateless
@EJB(name="ejb/checkName")
public class TestEJB implements ITestEJBRemoteInterface 
{
    List<String> moListOfNames = Arrays.asList("Kevin","Jiten","Martina","Brian"); 
    /** * Default constructor. */
    public TestEJB() 
    { 

    } 
    /** * Find if the passed name is present in the default list of names 
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * @return */ 
    public boolean checkNames(String fsName)
    { 
        boolean lboolNamePresent = false; 
        if(fsName != null) 
        { 
            lboolNamePresent = moListOfNames.contains(fsName); 
        } 
        return lboolNamePresent; 
    }
}
```

**ejb-jar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:ejb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd" version="3.1"> 
 <display-name> TestEJB3.1 </display-name> 
 </ejb-jar>
```

**EJB Deployment was successful and the log files throws the binding location:**

**java:global/TestEJB3.1EAR/TestEJB3.1/TestEJB!ejb31.test.ITestEJBRemoteInterface**

The problem is when invoking the ejb.
**WebSphereClient.java**

```
package com.client;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class WebSphereClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String jndiPath = "corbaname:rir:#ejb/global/TestEJB3.1EAR/TestEJB3.1/TestEJB!ejb31.test.ITestEJBRemoteInterface";
        String provider = "corbaname:iiop:localhost:2809";

        Properties jndiLookupProps = new Properties();
        jndiLookupProps.put(javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
         com.ibm.websphere.naming.PROPS.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
        jndiLookupProps.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, provider);
        try {
            Object found = new InitialContext().lookup(jndiPath);
        } catch (NamingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It throws an error:
javax.naming.InvalidNameException: The name component "TestEJB!ejb31.test.ITestEJBRemoteInterface" violates INS name syntax.  There is more than one unescaped ID/KIND separator (".").

**When i tried escaping the jndiPath like:**

```
jndiPath = "corbaname:rir:#ejb/global/TestEJB3%5c.1EAR/TestEJB3%5c.1/TestEJB!ejb31%5c.test%5c.ITestEJBRemoteInterface";
```

or

```
jndiPath = "corbaname:rir:#ejb/global/TestEJB3\.1EAR/TestEJB3\.1/TestEJB!ejb31\.test\.ITestEJBRemoteInterface";
```

or

```
jndiPath = "corbaname:rir:#ejb/global/TestEJB3\\.1EAR/TestEJB3\\.1/TestEJB!ejb31\\.test\\.ITestEJBRemoteInterface";
```

**It gives the same error.
How to invoke the EJB deployed in the Websphere liberty properly using a remote client?**

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for ages trying to get something like the above working. I.e. access an EJB from standalone Java client. Not successful.
However, I did manager to get access to remote EJB lookup and invocation working when I ran the client code from another WLP instance. This works fine. Below is the method used in the client side WLP to find a remote EJB and invoke a method.

```
    public void invokeRemoteMethod() {
    dbg("invokeRemoteMethod called");
    String jndiName = "corbaname::localhost:2809/NameService#ejb/global/app1EAR/app1EJB/CalcImpl!test\\.CalcRemote";
    Hashtable<String,String> env = new Hashtable<String,String>();
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "corbaloc:iiop:localhost:2809");
    try {
        Context initialContext = new InitialContext(env);
        Object remoteObj = initialContext.lookup(jndiName);
        System.out.println("remoteObj found = " + ((remoteObj == null) ? "null" : remoteObj.getClass().getName()));
        CalcRemote remoteBean = CalcRemote.class.cast(PortableRemoteObject.narrow(remoteObj, CalcRemote.class));
        System.out.println("remoteBean name = " + ((remoteBean == null) ? remoteBean : remoteBean.getClass().getName()));
        System.out.println("add 1, 3 =" + remoteBean.add(1, 3));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Another thing, I had to copy the files key.p12 and ltpa.keys from ..\usr\servers<server-name>\resources\security* of the server WLP instance to the client WLP instance. And you will need to setup the ports on the client side WLP so that they do not conflict.

It is likely that if you want to invoke a remote method via standalone Java client, you will be better to implement a SOAP based web service.